# Best practice for an animated image gallery with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a photo gallery. I have this code:

```
<head>
<style>
.thumb {
    max-height: 171px;
    border: solid 6px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.8);
}

.box {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    opacity: 0;
}

.box img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.box:target {
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.box:target img {
    border: solid 17px rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.8);
}

.light-btn {
    color: #fafafa;
    background-color: #333;
    border: solid 3px #777;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.light-btn:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
    top: 2%;
    color: #fafafa;
    background-color: #92001d;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-close:hover {
    background-color: #740404;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#img1"><img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"></a>
<a href="#img2"><img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562657548-fcab42b43035?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=332&q=80"></a>
<a href="#img3"><img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564249332652-bf435bb2d21f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=353&q=80"></a>

<div class="box" id="img1">
<a href="#img3" class="light-btn btn-prev">prev</a>
<a href="#_" class="btn-close">X</a>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
<a href="#img2" class="light-btn btn-next">next</a>
</div>

<div class="box" id="img2">
<a href="#img1" class="light-btn btn-prev">prev</a>
<a href="#_" class="btn-close">X</a>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562657548-fcab42b43035?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=332&q=80">
<a href="#img3" class="light-btn btn-next">next</a>
</div>

<div class="box" id="img3">
<a href="#img2" class="light-btn btn-prev">prev</a>
<a href="#_" class="btn-close">X</a>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564249332652-bf435bb2d21f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=353&q=80">
<a href="#img1" class="light-btn btn-next">next</a>
</div>
</body>
```

But I want to add animation. I want the photos to come from the left when I click on "next" and from the right when I click on "prev", like a slider.
Is it possible to achieve it with CSS?  For example with transform property? If not what script should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with radio buttons. If you have a radio button at the top for each transition you want to make, you can use CSS to select on every radio button there is and add the CSS transitions as needed. Use `<label>`s instead of `<a>`s to check the radio buttons, and then make the actual radio buttons invisible. But this would take a lot of code and wouldn't scale very well. So if you plan on having more images, you have to add CSS for each on individually, which can be a lot of work.

Here is a quick example putting the images into a reel and sliding the whole thing side to side. It may not be exactly what you want, but it is much less code. It's at least a good starting place.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .thumb {
      max-height: 171px;
      border: solid 6px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.8);
    }

    .reel-wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 999;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
      text-align: center;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .reel {
      position: absolute;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      transition: left 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #radio-close:not(:checked) ~ .reel-wrapper {
      outline: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .box {
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .box img {
      max-width: 90%;
      max-height: 80%;
      margin-top: 2%;
      border: solid 17px rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.8);
    }

    input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #radio-img1:checked ~ .reel-wrapper .reel {
      left: 0;
    }
    #radio-img2:checked ~ .reel-wrapper .reel {
      left: -100vw;
    }
    #radio-img3:checked ~ .reel-wrapper .reel {
      left: -200vw;
    }
    

    .light-btn {
      color: #fafafa;
      background-color: #333;
      border: solid 3px #777;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      border-radius: 1px;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: absolute;
      top: 45vh;
      z-index: 99;
    }

    .light-btn:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }

    .btn-close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 2%;
      top: 2%;
      color: #fafafa;
      background-color: #92001d;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border-radius: 1px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .btn-close:hover {
      background-color: #740404;
    }
    
    .btn-prev {
      left: 5vw;
    }
    
    .btn-next {
      right: 5vw;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="radio-close" type="radio" name="gallery-nav" checked>
  <input id="radio-img1"  type="radio" name="gallery-nav">
  <input id="radio-img2"  type="radio" name="gallery-nav">
  <input id="radio-img3"  type="radio" name="gallery-nav">
  
  <label for="radio-img1"><img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"></label>
  <label for="radio-img2"><img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562657548-fcab42b43035?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=332&q=80"></label>
  <label for="radio-img3"><img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564249332652-bf435bb2d21f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=353&q=80"></label>

  <div class="reel-wrapper">
    <div class="reel">

      <div class="box" id="img1">
        <label for="radio-img3" class="light-btn btn-prev">prev</label>
        <label for="radio-close" class="btn-close">X</label>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
        <label for="radio-img2" class="light-btn btn-next">next</label>
      </div>

      <div class="box" id="img2">
        <label for="radio-img1" class="light-btn btn-prev">prev</label>
        <label for="radio-close" class="btn-close">X</label>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562657548-fcab42b43035?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=332&q=80">
        <label for="radio-img3" class="light-btn btn-next">next</label>
      </div>

      <div class="box" id="img3">
        <label for="radio-img2" class="light-btn btn-prev">prev</label>
        <label for="radio-close" class="btn-close">X</label>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564249332652-bf435bb2d21f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=353&q=80">
        <label for="radio-img1" class="light-btn btn-next">next</label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Typically this kind of thing would be easier to do with JavaScript. You could just keep track of which image you are looking at, and then on clicking a button toggle the right classes to make CSS do the actual animation. It is much easier to manage for scale. But pure CSS solutions are always more fun.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, but I don't want the buttons to move with the slider. I want them to stay in one position. I know that changing position property won't work with next and prev buttons, so how can I do this other way?

Comment: You could move the buttons so they float over the reel and are all stacked on top of each other, with all but the current buttons set to `display:none`. When you click the buttons, which are actually labels, the css will select on the radio button and hide those buttons and show the buttons for the new image. Now the buttons look like they don't move.

Comment: Also, if you don't like the reel and you want to be able to click next forever and always have the images slide to the left, you could use [`keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) to start the new image on the right, and then animate it sliding to the left.